# Do accelerators or incubators help to getting visa?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, germany, visa

If I have a MVP(Minimum viable Product = creating a prototype of a tech invention or idea) that I like to find an investor or create a startup around it in UK/Germany/US/Canada, applying for accelerators or incubators can help me to get visa or I must go for visa in other ways?

I live in Iran.

Comment: What is an MVP?  What kind of visa do you want?  What do you mean by accelerators and incubators, and what does it mean to apply for them?

Comment: @phoog: I updated my question about `MVP` . For accelerator & incubator please see this: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/accelerators-vs-incubators-what-startups-need-to-know/

Comment: For the UK, there is https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur